# How to get year from string date c#

Tags: sql

I have string date in sql server, and I want to retrieve all the rows greater than or equal the year of 2018 using ADO.Net. This is what I've accomplished but the `result.HasRows()` **returns false** although I already have rows in that table.

Is it something related to Culture?

---

**UPDATE:**
the problem was in data itself. there were some date in different format. it works now.

```
using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
{
    command.CommandText = $"SELECT *
                          $"FROM [dbo].[tableName] " +
                          $"WHERE Year(CAST([tableNmae].Date as datetime)) >= {2018}  ";

     using (var result = command.ExecuteReader())
     {
        if (result.HasRows)
        {
             while (result.Read())
             {}
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I doubt that this is a C# issue really. Have you tried performing the query in SQL Server Explorer or whatever it's called now? I very much expect this is a SQL issue.

Comment: This is a SQL Server issue, not issue connected with C#. Try using the same query in SSMS. Do you get any record?

Comment: Maybe you should use `CONVERT` instead of `CAST` and pass the format of your date strings, to be sure the datestrings aren't interpreted false.

Comment: This is a SQL question not C#.  So assuming the column in the table 'Date' is a valid  datetime, I would imagine you need to change from `cast` to `convert` and use with of the numeric indicators to tell SQL what format your date is in.  Then your `>=` will work, `year()` is a integer so it'll be `>=2018`

Comment: You have a typo in your SQL `CAST([tableNmae].Date` im assuimg it should be `CAST([tableName].Date` note the spelling of `tableName`

Comment: Is there something missing from the `command.CommandText = $"SELECT *` line?

Comment: @Jon Skeet yes and I got an error. The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value. although  I've already used the same syntax (year cast) in another query from the same table and it works fine!

Comment: @Darko Martinovic no I got error

Comment: @ schlonzo same error.

Comment: @cjb110  also error

Comment: @akaBase typo error is just here, it is correct in my code.

Comment: @Andrew Morton the missing concatenation is just here.

Comment: Can you share the date list in the database?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use **CAST** for the **string** type. You should use **CONVERT** instead of **CAST**

**Why 104?** Because I took this website as a reference.

http://www.sqlusa.com/bestpractices/datetimeconversion/

```
using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
{
    command.CommandText = $"SELECT *
                          $"FROM [dbo].[tableName] " +
                          $"WHERE Year(CONVERT(DATETIME,[tableNmae].Date,104)) >= {2018}  ";

     using (var result = command.ExecuteReader())
     {
        if (result.HasRows)
        {
             while (result.Read())
             {}
        }
     }
}
```

NOTE: To use CONVERT, the column must not be of **ntext** type.

If you use it you will get this error.

> Explicit conversion from data type ntext to datetime is not allowed.

Sample error if you don't use the correct dial type

[image]

Comment: I got this error message in sql server. "The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value." my col type is char.

Comment: @eva because you used false reference. Did you review the link I shared? Example: dd.mm.yyyy format 104, mm/dd/yyyy format 101. Sen kendi veri formatına uygun çevirme kullanmadın. I used 104. Because my date format is dd.mm.yyyy. Örnek tarih verisi paylaşır mısın?